# how to strip replace special characters

Tags: php

I am trying to strip special characters and multiple empty lines from an email currently I am using a combination of strip replace and tags but is having some issues.

php:

```
$message=strip_tags($message, "<br><p><u><span><hr><section>");
$message=preg_replace("/(<br\ ?\/?>)+/", "<br/>", $message);
$message=preg_replace( "/\s+/", " ", $message );
$message = str_replace('<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>', '', $message);
```

output is:

```
________________________________________
Hi,



My comp= uter and php code is acting up.
= 



This is just= a test email with whitespaces J



=   
= =
```

I am sending a message with outlook and it looks like it's replacing every empty lines with

```
<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
```

how can I replace that with nothing, remove multiple empty lines and remove all the = characters. Any suggestions?

Original typed message looks like this:

```
Hi,

My computer and php code is acting up.

This is just a test email with whitespaces :)
```

And this is what outlook code looks like before sending the email.

```
<p class=MsoNormal style='mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'><span
style='mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:
Calibri;color:black'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

<p class=MsoNormal>Hi,<o:p></o:p></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

<p class=MsoNormal>My computer and php code is acting up.<o:p></o:p></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

<p class=MsoNormal>This is just a test email with whitespaces <span
style='font-family:Wingdings'>J</span><o:p></o:p></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

</div>
```



Thanks.

Comment: in your str_replace you are replacing `<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>` with `''`(empty space) not `''` empty space with `<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>`

Comment: yea but for some reason its not replacing. maybe because of the space between <p class ?

Comment: please show the original $message

Comment: I updated my question. please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the perfect solution, but seems to work:

```
<?php

$s = 'Hi,



My comp= uter and php code is acting up.
= 



This is just= a test email with whitespaces J



=   
= = ';

$s = preg_replace('/=\s/', '', $s);
$s = preg_replace('/\n\n/', "", $s);
echo $s;
```

prints

```
Hi,My computer and php code is acting up.
This is justa test email with whitespaces J
```

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML Purifier - It is a standards-compliant HTML filter library written in PHP.

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.